# Bound for $\left|\int_{s}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt\right|$

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't follow the arguments below to obtain the given absolute bound. Any additional intermediate step would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

For any $s > 0$, there exists an integer number $k \geq 0$ such that $s \in (k \pi, (k+1) \pi]$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\int_{s}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt\right| & = &  \left| \int_{s}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt + \sum_{m=k+1}^{\infty} \int_{m \pi}^{(m+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt \right| \\
& \leq & \left| \int_{s}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt \right| + \left| \int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt \right|\\
& \leq & \frac{2 \pi}{|s|}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

The choice of the intervals guarantees that the series is an alternating one. So it is bounded in absolute value by its first term. That and the triangle inequality takes you from the first line to the second one.

From the second to the third line, 
$$
 \left| \int_{s}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt \right| + \left| \int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt \right|\leq  \int_{s}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin t|}{t} dt  + \int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{|\sin t|}{t} dt \\
\leq \int_{s}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{1}{t} dt  + \int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{1}{t} dt 
= \int_{s}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{1}{t} dt\leq \int_{s}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{1}{s} dt=\dfrac{(k+2)\pi-s}{s}\leq\dfrac{2\pi}s
$$

Answer (score 1):

So start exactly as you have. You see that $\int_s^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt $ is some finite thing and can be bounded independent of $s.$

Now the other more interesting part, is $\int_{(k+1)\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$. You split it into intervals of length $\pi,$ and estimate it using the alternating series:

$$
\int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} \leq \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi} \int_{(k+1)\pi}^{(k+2)\pi} \sin t.
$$
The last integral alternates sign but is constant in magnitude with $k.$ Remembering that the alternating series converges, you're done.